# TFS vs2005 always get on accessing a file

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

In vs2005 opening a file causes a dialog to pop up "Contacting server to get a list of items to update"... everytime... I'm not checking out / editing ... just opening to view.

Reset vs2005 settings etc ... but to no avail ... 
No settings appear to be diff. between mine and other devs boxes here.
Appears to be nothing on google.
No addins etc

driving me nuts - anytime something changes on the server I get the change ... not to mention the interruption.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously not normal behaviour as you can tell from looking at the other developers machines.  I would personally suspect a plug-in of some sort.  You could try looking in Tools, Add-in Manager to see if anything is there.  If that doesn't work, close Visual Studio and start a Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt and then type

```
devenv /SafeMode
```

And see if the problem still occurs.  If it does you could try resetting Visual Studio by typing the following at a Visual Studo 2005 command prompt (warning it will reset all your preferences etc)

```
devenv /ResetSettings
```

But all of these are a shot in the dark - I've never seen the behaviour that you are describing...

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.

The safemode trick works ... I think because TFS integration isn't enabled tho ...

ResetSettings hasn't helped any...

I've checked the addins ... nothing there that would cause this sort of thing and it continues if I disable them all.